# path.basename of / gives back empty string

Tags: node.js, path

Node.js `path.basename` of `/` gives back empty string `''` Its pretty clear why it happens but still a bit confusing.

Is it implemented by design or a bug?

```
path.basename('/') 
// => ''
```

In the same time `path.dirname` of `/` giving back `/`

```
path.dirname('/') 
// => '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked the documentation of [Path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext),

`path.basename()` methods returns the last portion of a path, similar to the Unix basename command.

For Example:

```
path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html');
// Returns: 'quux.html'
```

So as in your case it is `/` so it is returning empty string.